# Jmeter login script

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter for testng load balance of website.I written a script to test the scenario like to make the user to login into the website and able navigate the user to the dashboard where he can see the recent data by consuming the protected calls.Here i am able to pass the user login scenario but the jmeter showing fail errors regarding the protected calls.When i am searching the url thing whcih is given by jmeter i able to understand that teh protected calls need user credentials to consume data but it fails due to absence of user login things.

Comment: How did you create the JMeter script? Did you do any correlation of the session variables?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Here i am able to pass the user login scenario

are you sure? If JMeter reports the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler as successful it doesn't necessarily mean that the login will be successful, it might be the case your application responds with [status code 200](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) and some error message explaining why the login has failed and JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful.

Try inspecting request and response details using View Results Tree listener which has `HTML` and `Browser` modes and double check that you're able to login.

- If yes - you might need to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) or perform the [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/) of the authorization header in the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) for the "protected calls" or something like this
- If no - you will need to amend your script so login will be successful. In order to avoid such situations in future you might want to add [Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) to your test plan to ensure that JMeter is doing what it's supposed to be doing